# Chromesetup.exe disappearing

Tags: windows-xp, google-chrome

I'm having this crazy problem where I can't install Chrome as the Chromesetup (and Chrome offline setup). I double click on the setup application, and then nothing happens

I'm running windows xp.

I tried to use process explorer, and I can see a process starting and then after a second or two the process disappear.

I don't know if there are any logs written anywhere or anything like that.. but I can't figure out what's happening.

Any ideas anyone?
Regards

Comment: No one ever seen this problem before? 
Is there an easy way to step through and debug it, to see why it's failing? I tried to save a process monitor file/registry activity dump, it shows that the setup runs for about 1second, and accesses a lot of files and registry keys, I also suspect it's extracting the setup files...

Comment: I can't simulate this.

Comment: It's possible that Chrome does a version check on Windows, realizes it's XP, then halts the installation without informing you fully.

I'm having trouble finding official word that newer versions of Chrome will not install on older versions of Windows - just that Chrome will "continue to work", with the assumption being that it's already installed.  It's very likely that newer packages do a Windows version check and terminate if not meeting [Google requirements](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/7100626?hl=en) (there are also processor requirements listed which you might not meet).

Answer (score 0):

Run `cmd` go to user temp dir `cd /d %temp%`, delete all files and folders `rd . /q /s`, run setup, find log in temp...
Probably your AV delete temp setup files, check AV quarantine and log.